# how to zoom image when mouse hover in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

zoom in image when i put mouse pointer how to do in selenium webdriver using java code.please if possible provide some sample code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? We will not write the code for you but we can help with any specific problems you have. Have you tried searching with Google for image zooming?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Keys.chord()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#chord%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29) method to press Ctrl+ to Zoom:

```
//Replace it with image element locator in findElement
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("img"));
//Repeat the following statement, till you get desired zoom level.
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD));
```

CAUTION: Selenium works at 100% zoom level and throws error if it is not.

To reset Zoom, use the following piece of code:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "0"));
```